# Validating / filtering items added to associated collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Let's say I have `@Entity` declared with collection like that:

`@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();`

Later on, you can get access to it by calling `<my entity>/{id}/users`.

If there's any kind of insert into that collection (through `POST`, `PATCH` or `PUT` and `text/uri-list` content type), I want to make sure that you can add only those users which match some condition (e.g. `user.age >= 18`).
If client tries to add anything else, endpoint should return error or at least ignore unmatched users.

How do I do that?

I've tried `@Where` clause, but it's simply injected into `SELECT` queries, although rows are actually inserted into DB.
I've tried `@FilterJoinTable`, like here:

`@FilterJoinTable(name = "hasRightAge", condition = "age >= 18")
private Set<StorageUser> users = new HashSet<>();`

But it doesn't have any effect.

I might also use Spring's `Validator` but there must be some better way of doing it.

Comment: Take a look at Bean Validation/Hibernate Validator.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion I've tried using `ConstraintValidator`. Its validation methods are fired off when doing `PATCH` request with new set of users, but they are not fired off when adding one new item to collection using `POST` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using custom validator attached to `beforeLinkSave` event.

```
   @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        super.configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(validatingListener);

        MyCustomValidator validator = new MyCustomValidator(...);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeLinkSave", validator);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation `@Min(18)` on your field.
It's from the Hibernate Validator : http://hibernate.org/validator/

You can also use Spring's Bean validation in a similar way. Spring will fail directly in the controller, while Hibernate will fail later on commit.

Comment: I need to do a validation on a custom entity (`User`) and only in place of that collection, not on primitive type of a single object. I am trying to use custom constraint annotation, like here: http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/. From what I see - validation is called when I directly call `CrudRepository` methods, but they are not called while using auto-generated endpoints coming from `spring-data-rest`. In other words, when I do POST request to that collection, validation does not fire off.